# only last option from theme options is being saved to the DB

Tags: wp-admin, theme-options, add-menu-page

I have this admin page functions where I am trying to prompt the admin for some text data.

the problem that is only the last field is being saved and existed ain the DB, the top ones do not exist in the DB at all.

adding options to admin page:

```
 register_setting( 'top-data-group', 'yourLogo');
 register_setting( 'card1-group', 'card1_text');
 register_setting( 'card4-group', 'card4_text');


  add_settings_section('top-options', 'Top Information', 'top_options', 'top-data' );
  add_settings_section('card1', 'Card 1', 'card1_options', 'top-data' );
  add_settings_section('card4', 'Card 4', 'top_options', 'top-data' );


 add_settings_field('yourLogo', 'Logo Image URL:', 'yourLogoImage_callback', 'top-data', 'top-options'  );
 add_settings_field('card1_text', 'card 1 text:', 'card1_text_callback', 'top-data', 'card1'  );
 add_settings_field('card4_text', 'card 4 text:', 'card4_text_callback', 'top-data', 'card4'  );
```

callback functions:

```
function card1_text_callback (){
    $preText =  esc_attr( get_option('card1_text'));
     echo ' <input type="text" name="card1_text" placeholder="card text" size="50" value="'.$preText. '" > ';
 }


function card4_text_callback (){
    $preText =  esc_attr( get_option('card4_text'));
     echo ' <input type="text" name="card4_text" placeholder="card text" size="50" value="'.$preText. '" > ';
 }

function yourLogoImage_callback (){
    $preText =  esc_attr( get_option('yourLogoImage'));
     echo ' <input type="text" name="yourLogoImage" placeholder="your Logo Image URL" size="50" value="'.$preText. '" > <p> use external or internal image url , preferred (300 * 50 px) </p>'   ;
 }
```

the form page:

```
<h1> Top Section </h1>
<?php settings_errors(); ?>


<form action="options.php" method="post" >  
    <?php 


    settings_fields('top-data-group');
    do_settings_sections('top-data');

    settings_fields('card1-group');
    do_settings_sections('card1');

    settings_fields('card4-group');
    do_settings_sections('card4');

    submit_button('save', 'primary sub-button', 'submit', true);

  ?>
</form>
```

only last option is being saved to the db, top ones are all empty.

Comment: Which "top ones"? But one issue I see is, the `yourLogoImage` in your `yourLogoImage_callback()` doesn't match the one in your `register_setting()` call.

Comment: yeah, `register_setting()` matches the `add_setting_field()` id .. I've done the same with card4 and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it as follows:

1- `regester_setting()` id should not match any other Id, and this is the Id you have to 
    use in the callback function.

2- you don't need to use `add_setting_field()` id in any place.

3- put all sections in one option group.

4- the page inside `add_settings_section()` and `add_setting_field()` should match the page slug that being rendered by `add_menu_page()` or `add_submenu_page()`.

so the code now as follows:

adding options to admin page:

change: deleted every group options, only one saved and added to every `regester_settings()`. changed the page slug to match page on the `add_settings_field()`.

```
    add_submenu_page('top', 'top', 'top', 'manage_options', 'top-data', 'top_init' );


 register_setting( 'top-data-group', 'yourLogo');
 register_setting( 'top-data-group', 'card1_text');
 register_setting( 'top-data-group', 'card4_text');


  add_settings_section('top-options', 'Top Information', 'top_options', 'top-data' );
  add_settings_section('card1', 'Card 1', 'card1_options', 'top-data' );
  add_settings_section('card4', 'Card 4', 'top_options', 'top-data' );


 add_settings_field('random3', 'Logo Image URL:', 'yourLogoImage_callback', 'top-data', 'top-options'  );
 add_settings_field('crandom1', 'card 1 text:', 'card1_text_callback', 'top-data', 'card1'  );
 add_settings_field('random2', 'card 4 text:', 'card4_text_callback', 'top-data', 'card4'  );
```

callback functions:

change: changed `get_options()` an `name=` properties to match ids on the `regester_settings()`

```
function card1_text_callback (){
    $preText =  esc_attr( get_option('card1_text'));
     echo ' <input type="text" name="card1_text" placeholder="card text" size="50" value="'.$preText. '" > ';
 }


function card4_text_callback (){
    $preText =  esc_attr( get_option('card4_text'));
     echo ' <input type="text" name="card4_text" placeholder="card text" size="50" value="'.$preText. '" > ';
 }

function yourLogoImage_callback (){
    $preText =  esc_attr( get_option('yourLogo'));
     echo ' <input type="text" name="yourLogoImage" placeholder="your Logo Image URL" size="50" value="'.$preText. '" > <p> use external or internal image url , preferred (300 * 50 px) </p>'   ;
 }
```

the form page:

change: delete every group option, only one saved.

```
<h1> Top Section </h1>
<?php settings_errors(); ?>


<form action="options.php" method="post" >  
    <?php 


    settings_fields('top-data-group');
    do_settings_sections('top-data');



    submit_button('save', 'primary sub-button', 'submit', true);

  ?>
</form>
```

Comment: You haven't corrected the `name="yourLogoImage"`..

Comment: yeah your right

Comment: You should edit your answer and correct it, including typos like 'regester' which should be 'register'.